# Access 2010: How to show only two decimals after comma for currency field

Tags: ms-access-2010, number-formatting

This has been annoying me for quite some time now and I cannot fine a solution for this. Maybe you have a hint for me? 
I've a field defined as number (double) with a precision of 2 decimal places; format as Euro. I did create a form based on that table - which shows correct format for that particular field. However, when I want to edit the value in that field and click it, the number changes to something really nasty: 
e.g. 5,90€ changes to 5,90000009536743.
Funny thing: it looks like not all entries behave in that manner. I did execute the ROUND(field, 2) sql update query for that field, but it didn't help.

Many thanks for your help!

N.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is caused by the way a double is stored on harddisc or RAM: It's just no .0 with any type of floating. You should use currency to store such a value.

Comment: Well, I tried to update the field with ROUND - but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use currency as datatype of the column, not double or you will always have such issues.